# How to get started with Polymerfire?

Tags: firebase, polymer

**UPDATE:**
Following my ramblings below, I have since managed to login via google using the popup but why it works now is unclear. I have done two additional things (that I know of) and everything else remains the same. New things are:

1. I have created a fresh firebase console project and re-added the necessary auth methods as before (I do not think the fact that this is a fresh project is relevant to the solution)
2. While before i was working locally, I have now deployed-to-firebase and checked the deployed version of the site and THEN logged in locally (I can almost see why this might be a requirement)

Maybe somebody in the know can shed some light at some point. More generally, it would be nice to know how to troubleshoot some of these errors because one does not know what a blank popup really means.

---

**PROBLEM:** When I try to sign in with popup (Google as provider) I get a blank page (or blank popup). I see some 'service worker' errors when debugging but I have no idea what they mean - these are them:

```
The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
GET https://PROJECT.firebaseapp.com/service-worker.js net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

I have configured email and Google as auth providers in the Firebase project console.

My polymer project setup is elementary. I set up one of the blank Polymer starter kit apps and ran to check. Then I installed Polymerfire with Bower and added a bunch of elements as references. For example:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/polymerfire.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase.html">
```

Then I created a simple app with a login button and added the firebase-app and firebase-auth elements following the steps on the polymerfire github project but replacing the app keys etc. for my firebase project (which I set up recently in the firebase console). I wont reproduce the code here but it has the basic elements

```
firebase-app, firebase-auth, paper-button
```

I assume because my project is so simple and I have used the code exactly as suggested in the Polymerfire github project that I need to add some other init code or something? Although I acknowledge the existence of the demo project, I could not find any step by step instructions for this so I feel like the guy who is missing something that everyone else knows. So any pointers would be much appreciated as I am trying to learn the best practices for using Polymer and Firebase together (I just discovered these a few days ago).

Note: i setup a sample without using polymerfire and 'directly' used the firebase sdk - and i had the same issue. I can log in with email and password for a user i add manually via the firebase console but I cannot login using the popup and google provider. This, despite setting up i.e. "enabling" the google auth provider in the firebase project console. Instructions suggest simply enabling and pressing save should suffice

Comment: ^ Please edit items into your question, rather than adding them as comments.